# php, pdo mysql can't insert with inner join

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm a little stuck with the following. I have two tables, projects and change.

Projects:

```
- id
- title
- description
- datecreated
```

Change:

```
- id
- title
- description
- projectid FOREIGN KEY
- datecreated
```

i can't figure out how to

```
insert into change (name, description, projectid) value (:name, :description, :projectid)
select id from project
where name = $name
```

important - the name and description in the insert are provided by php variables using a form.

important - must use PDO

Actual Code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO change (title, description, project_id) SELECT :title, :description, id FROM project WHERE title = :project_title";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(":title" => $title, ":description" => $description, ":project_title" => $created));
```

This is what I did in the end but Barmar gets the point for help on this and another question.

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO `change` (`title`, `description`, `project_id`) SELECT :title, :description, id FROM project WHERE title = :project_title";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(":title" => $title, ":description" => $description, ":project_title" => $created));
```

Comment: Please don't use some tag only in the meaning "I want you write a code for me using certain technology". thank you.

Comment: Is there a difference between the name in the `:name` placeholder and the one in `$name` variable? Why are you using variable substitution with PDO -- you obviously know how to use placeholders, you should use them all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert, you either use a `values` clause or you use `select` to specify the source of the data. You can't use both.

You want:

```
INSERT INTO `change` (`title`, `description`, `projectid`)
SELECT :title, :description, id
FROM project
WHERE title = :project_title
```

Comment: Why is there a colon `:` in the `description` column? Typo?

Comment: From what the definition in the question tells, the name columns in project and changes are unrelated. Instead, the project name should be injected with another placeholder like :projectname. @asprin: The colon denotes a parameter injected into the prepared statement (a named placeholder).

Comment: I'll wait for an answer to my question in the comments above.

Comment: @Lukas Ah I see, but then why isn't it there for `name` and `id` on this line `SELECT name, :description, id FROM project`?

Comment: @asprin Because `name` and `id` are coming from the `project` table, `:description` comes from the user input.

Comment: Thanks, but according to the OP, `name` and `description` are coming through user input. So shouldn't it be `SELECT :name, :description, id FROM project`? Sorry for these lame questions, just trying to figure out some basics.

Comment: I'm matching `:name` in the `WHERE` clause. So the `name` coming from the table will be the same as the `:name` in the user input. You're not allowed to use a placeholder twice in the same query, so I did it this way.

Comment: Wow, great discussion! I'm not sure i follow though. The end result should insert a row into change table where name is supplied by user input, description is supplied by user input and project_id is populated by a look up within the projects table to match a "second" name variable with id from projects.

Comment: Hope that makes sense? I'm supplying the following variable from a form. $name, $description, $projectname. I want the project id inserted not the project name as users remember names not id.

Comment: It might be helpful if I supply the actual live code: Please check out the original question.

Comment: It looks like your updated query should work, I've updated my answer to match it -- I think my original answer pointed you in the right direction. If it's not working, please explain what's wrong and we can try to resolve it.

Comment: Barmar, you helped me just a minute ago on the other question also. I reworked the about code to something I was more comfortable with. Please see the original question above for details :-)

Comment: Barmar, actually I looked at the earlier code we had worked on and applied the same rules of using back ticks and that worked also. So i've used the shortened more efficient code. Thanks again!!